# How can I get the "Windows.h" and "conio.h" headers in Xcode to use for a C program?

Tags: c, xcode, include

I came across some source code for a "snake" game implemented in the C programming language. I am trying to compile this game code in Xcode. However, when I try to compile it, I get an error saying that "Windows.h" and "conio.h" files do not exist. These headers are #included in the C source code.

Where can I get copies of these required "Windows.h" and "conio.h" header files? Why are they not provided already by Xcode? What are the replacements?

Comment: I can assure you those two headers are the least of your worries if you're planning on compiling a windows console program for OS X or iOS with Xcode/clang. The entire console API is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

windows.h and conio.h are specific to the Microsoft windows operating system . They are not available and make no sense in IOS.